# Can $A \times B$ give you a circle of radius $1$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, parametrization

I've heard that $A \times B$ cannot be a circle of radius $1$. However I think this is false as I know from $\sin^2 x+\cos^2 x=1$. So can we take the set $A=\{\sin \theta | \theta \in R \}$ and $B=\{\cos \theta | \theta \in R\}$ or does this not work?

Comment: Can someone edit it so there is { } I tried searching how to do it but can't find it.

Comment: To make the curly brackets appear, use \{  in place of {.

Comment: As to your example, the cartesian product of two sets is the collection of ALL pairs that can be drawn, one element from each of two sets.  Thus your example is, essentially, $[-1,1]\times [-1,1]$ which is a square.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your construction gives $[-1,1] \times [-1,1]$ because the two sets you've written down are those two closed intervals (and the set product is *every* pair of things where the first is from the first interval and the second is from the second interval).  However, there is a stupid way to do this ...

Let $A$ be a circle of radius $1$ and $B = \{0\}$.  Then $A \times B$ is still a circle of radius $1$.  It's elements are just written like "$(a,0)$" where $a$ is any point in a circle of radius $1$.  But the second element is constant, so this is homeomorphic to $A$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $S^1 $ be the circle of radius 1. Suppose $S^1 = A \times B $. Then
$(1,0) \in S_1$ and so $1 \in A$. Similarly $1 \in B$ and so
$(1,1) \in A \times B$. But $\|(1,1)\| = \sqrt{2}$ hence $S^1 \neq A \times B$.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $A \times B$ is a circle (i.e. a ring) of positive radius. Note that for any $a \in A$, the set $\{a\} \times B$ is bijective to $B$ via the map $(a,b) \mapsto b$. Now, if $a$ is the $x$-coordinate of the center point of our circle, then $\{a\} \times B$ has exactly two points and hence $B$ has exactly two points. On the other hand, if $a' \in A$ is a point where the tangent on our circle is parallel to the $y$-axis, then $\{ a' \} \times B$ only contains a single point and hence $B$ may only contain one element. Contradiction!

Comment: In case you want to avoid a proof by contradiction - the above is easily rephrased to be a 'natural' proof.

Answer (score 2):

In your example $A$ and $B$ are both the set $[-1,1]$, so $A\times B$ is just a filled-in rectangle.

There's no way for a carteseian product to specify that you only want to pair elements that arise from the same $\theta$.

You can write $\{\langle x,y\rangle\mid \exists\theta: x=\cos\theta, y=\sin\theta \}$ for the unit circle, but that is not a cartesian product, because the conditions for $x$ and $y$ are not independent of each other.